# Error when trying to return Redirect in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When I submit a form in Laravel, the following controller method handles it:

```
public function update($id)
    {
        //handle input
        return View::make('generic.success', ["message" => 'Data submitted successfully!']);
    }
```

This works fine. However, instead of returning a view like above I'd like to return a redirect, because when I return the view directly, reloading the page resubmits the form.

So I tried to do this:

```
public function update($id)
    {
        //handle input

        return Redirect::to('/success', ['message' => 'Data submitted successfully!']);
    }
```

In my routes file I defined the success route:

```
Route::get('success', 'NotificationsController@success');
```

And set up a notification controller to display the view:

```
class NotificationsController extends BaseController {

    public function success($message)
    {
        return View::make('generic.success', ["message" => $message]);
    }
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error from Laravel:

```
InvalidArgumentException
The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.
```

I have no idea what this is supposed to tell me, and neither does Google apparently.

Can someone shed some light on this issue?

P.S.

Incidentally, being new to Laravel, I've noticed so far that Laravel's error reporting is very user-unfriendly, in that instead of telling me I have an issue with my router, or controller, or permissions, it displays these generic errors with no humane explanation of their cause. Is there a better way to troubleshoot problems in Laravel than relying on this?

For example, in the above incident, the error report points to this line of code...

```
public function setStatusCode($code, $text = null)
{
    $this->statusCode = $code = (int) $code;
    if ($this->isInvalid()) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The HTTP status code "%s" is not valid.', $code));
    }
```

...which is completely useless, as all it does is show me the code that printed the error itself.

Comment: When you use the `redirect::to()` function it shows error?

Comment: Yes. When I return a view (or anything else) it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the redirector's [`to()`](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_to) method is the HTTP status code that will be returned by the response, not data that will be passed along. Passing data when redirecting to `GET` routes can be done either via the query string or the session. The recommended solution here is to pass data via the current session using the `with()` method which passes that data for the next request. So in your case this would be the approach needed:

```php
public function update($id)
{
    return Redirect::to('/success')->with('message', 'Data submitted successfully!');
}
```

Then in your `success` method you can have this:

```php
public function success($message)
{
    return View::make('generic.success', ["message" => Session::get('message')]);
}
```

When in doubt always try checking the documentation first. The solution to this is explicitly stated in the [Laravel Response Redirects Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot -Bogdan I found in the documentation that you post answer to my problem. In my case the solution was redirect to an action in a controller, like this...

```
return 
    \Redirect::action(
        'PqrController@solicitud',
        array($id)
    )
    ->with(
        'message',
        '¡El estado de la solicitud ha sido actualizado correctamente!'
    )
;
```

I redirect to a method in a controller, with one parameter `array($id)` and I put too in the session a message using `->with('message','Mensaje')`